# get data from two different pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

Here is my problem. suppose by example, when I click on repeater row id then it will transfer to particular customers invoice.

But in customer invoice page, it opens only when customer Id logged in. So here two different pages accessing one page data. my code is as below.
In repeater's page.

```
     <th>
      <asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkbtnStmt" Text ="Statement" OnClick ="lnkbtnStmt_Click" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
      <asp:HiddenField ID ="hfStmt" runat ="server" Value='<% #Eval("No")%>'/>
     </th>
```

in repeater .cs page :

```
    public void lnkbtnStmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        int rptIndex = ((RepeaterItem)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer).ItemIndex;
        string hfItem = Convert.ToString(((HiddenField)RptEmpCustInvoise.Items[rptIndex].FindControl("hfStmt")).Value);

        Customer_Ledger_Entries custlist = new Customer_Ledger_Entries();
        List<Customer_Ledger_Entries_Filter> cFilter = new List<Customer_Ledger_Entries_Filter>();
        Customer_Ledger_Entries_Filter cfield = new Customer_Ledger_Entries_Filter();
        cfield.Field = Customer_Ledger_Entries_Fields.Customer_No;
        cfield.Criteria = hfItem;
        cFilter.Add(cfield);
        Customer_Ledger_Entries[] culist = cls.wsCustInvoice.ReadMultiple(cFilter.ToArray(), null, 1);
        if (culist.Length > 0) 
        {
            Response.Redirect("frmCustomerInvoice.aspx?Customer_No=" + hfItem);
        }
    }
```

And in another Customer page.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetOpeningBal();
                bindCustInvoice(objSession.getSession(HttpContext.Current, "NonEmpCode"));
                string empCustId = Request.QueryString["Customer_No"];
                if (empCustId.Length != 0)
                {
                    CustInvoice("empCustId");
                }
                GetClosingBal();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), string.Empty, "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
        }
    }
```

In this page,`bindCustInvoice()` method works when customer get logged in and `CustInvoice("empCustId");` method works when we clicked on repeater id.
can any one give me solution?

Comment: okay, so what is your question? The question can be more clear

Comment: so you mean by question is some one can access the repeater without logged in :O ?

Comment: no..as I mentioned in question, I need to transfer data from repeaters row id to particular customer's invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clicked on Repeater Id , try to send the Page Name from Query String . and check the page name in your another customer page

**Pseudo code**

```
 string PageName ="";
      if(Request.QueryString["PageName"] != null)
      {
       PageName= Request.QueryString["PageName"];
      }


    if(PageName != "")
    {
     string empCustId = Request.QueryString["Customer_No"];
                    if (empCustId.Length != 0)
                    {
                        CustInvoice("empCustId");
                    }
    }
    else{
      bindCustInvoice(objSession.getSession(HttpContext.Current, "NonEmpCode"));
    }
```

Comment: @webruster..I am new in asp.net. so how to pass pagename in URL?

Comment: @soniya pagename in sense any string you can keep , ex: string can be `foo` . so you yourself keeping a logic that `foo` is assigned at customer page so you need to enable method related to customer. in another page  that is what i meant to say